# Adding a new row to an Excel table using VBA, when there are other tables of different width below it

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add a new row to a table in Excel using VBA. This is relatively simple, however if I try to use the usual “ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Add” then I get an error that says “This won’t work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.” I understand why I’m getting this error (because a new row would move the cells in such a way that the table below would fall apart).

So, is there an elegant way to add a row to this table, preferably in such a way that an entire row is added (there is no data to worry about horizontally from the table)? I have some code I’ve written that adds a whole new row, however it relies on AutoFormat being enabled and also does not seem to consistently work when I’m dealing with a large number of tables (my original file has a lot more, the screenshot is just from a dummy file I made).

The reason why I’m trying to do this is that I have a few tables with a list of the same names but different horizontal lengths and trying to create a Macro that will add a new name to all the tables. I also experimented with resizing the tables but that never seemed to work very well. Please see screenshot and code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
Sub AddName()

Range("Table1").EntireRow(Range("Table1").Rows.Count).Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Insert
Selection.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Destination:=Selection
Selection.ClearContents
Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value = Name

End Sub
```

[http://i.imgur.com/a/1WGSI](https://i.imgur.com/a/1WGSI)

Comment: Would moving the lower tables to the right of the table you are inserting into, or to another sheet solve the problem?

Comment: Agreed with Mark. It would be best to first deal with the source of this kind of issue, the placing of your tables. Unless there is a specific reason why your tables must be arranged this way, you will inevitably run into issues any time you try to add data to them (even manually). That's not to say that they must move, but it will certainly complicate matters in general.

Comment: Unfortunately, moving the tables in this case is not really possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code first adds new row below `ListObject` and then resizes table:

```
With ActiveCell.ListObject
    ActiveSheet.Rows(.HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListRows.Count + 1).insert
    .Resize (ActiveSheet.Range(.HeaderRowRange(1, 1), Cells(.HeaderRowRange.Row + .ListRows.Count + 1, .ListColumns.Count)))
End With
```

of course you need to replace `ActiveCell.ListObject` and `Activesheet` with proper objects, this works for table that contains active cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

```
Sub AddName()
    Dim NewRow As Range
    Set NewRow = Range("Table1").EntireRow(Range("Table1").Rows.Count).Offset(1,0)

    'Excel will include the newrow into table automaticlly
    NewRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = "newvalue"
End Sub
```

Comment: Be wary of the implicit `ActiveSheet` reference in your code. This will rely on the `ActiveSheet` being the target of the action, and will fail if the incorrect sheet is active.

Comment: Can you please explain what your code does, and why it may help? Your suggestion may help others, but it is only as useful as the explanation of *How* it works and *Why* it is better than the original code.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the tables will maintain the same number of columns, there's an easy workaround. Just arrange the tables vertically so that the tables with more columns are above the tables with fewer columns.

So if you have 5 tables with (for example) 3, 4, 5, 5, and 6 columns, put the table with 6 columns at the top, the two tables with 5 columns below that, the table with 4 columns below those, and the table with 3 columns at the bottom. That should fix the problem.

Incidentally, this bug also happens when you attempt to add ListColumns to a table that's on the same sheet + to the left of another table that has more rows.